# Помогите написать асинхронную функцию

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, асинхронность

Нужно написать функцию, которая получает массив всех пользователей и передает его в функцию коллбэк.

Пример использования:

```js
getUsersInfo((users) => {
  console.log(users); // [ { name: 'Alex', age: 70 }, { name: 'Elon' } ]
});
```

Для получения данных вам предоставлены 2 асинхронные функции

`getUsersIds` - возвращает массив с идентификаторами пользователей.
`getUserInfo` - возвращает данные пользователя по заданному идентификатору:

```js
getUsersIds((ids) => {
  console.log(ids); // ['id2', 'id6']
});

getUserInfo('someUserId', (userInfo) => {
  console.log(userInfo); // { name: 'Alex', age: 70 }
});
```

Функция должна вызвать callback, переданный первым аргументом и передать туда массив данных о пользователях.

Порядок пользователей в результирующем массиве должен соответствовать порядку идентификаторов в массиве из getUsersIds

Решение должно быть следующего формата:

```js
const { getUserInfo, getUsersIds } = db;

function getUsersInfo(onLoad) {
  // код решения
}
```

Comment: Жаль промисифицировать нормально не выйдет =) Коллбеки неправильные)

Comment: @vp_arth, почему не выйдет? просто ветки error не будет - а так все то же самое

Comment: Нормально не выйдет — это значит нужно писать костыль вместо `require('promisify')`

Comment: @vp_arth, не костыль, а специализированное решение :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback-hell во всей красе. :)

```js
// const { getUserInfo, getUsersIds } = db;
// Демо функции, чтобы работало

const data = {
  id1: {name: 'Alice',   age: 62},
  id2: {name: 'Bob',     age: 28},
  id3: {name: 'Charlie', age: 10},
};
function getUsersIds(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb(Object.keys(data)), 100);
};
function getUserInfo(id, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb(data[id]), 10*data[id].age);
}


function getUsersInfo(onLoad) {
  // Начнём с получения идентификаторов
  getUsersIds(ids => {
    // Пустой массив, если пользователей нет
    if (ids.length === 0) return onLoad([]);
    
    // Подготовим массив необходимой длины
    const users = [];
    users.length = ids.length;
    // Счётчик коллбеков, нужен чтобы среагировать на последний
    let c = ids.length;

    // Перебираем идентификаторы, запускаем «асинхронные» функции
    // for (const [i, id] of Object.entries(ids)) {
    for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
      const id = ids[i];
      
      getUserInfo(id, user => {
        // Кладём полученного пользователя в нужное место в массиве
        users[i] = user;
        // Когда счётчик дошёл до нуля, вызываем onLoad
        if (!--c) onLoad(users);
      });
    }
  });
}

getUsersInfo(users => console.log(JSON.stringify(users)));
```

---

А теперь попробуем это облагородить)

```js
// const { getUserInfo, getUsersIds } = db;
// Демо функции, чтобы работало
const getUsersIds = (cb) => cb([1, 2, 3]);
const getUserInfo = (id, cb) => cb({1: {name: 'Alice'}, 2: {name: 'Bob'}, 3: {name: 'Charlie'}}[id]);

// Функция, улучшающая интерфейс предоставленных функций
const promisify = fn => (...args) => 
    new Promise((resolve) => fn(...args, res => resolve(res)));

let getUsersIds$ = promisify(getUsersIds);
const getUserInfo$ = promisify(getUserInfo);

// Promise-реализация, чтобы не менять интерфейс функции, необходимой по ТЗ
async function getUsersInfo$() {
  const ids = await getUsersIds$();
  return await Promise.all(ids.map(id => getUserInfo$(id)));
}

function getUsersInfo(onLoad) {
  getUsersInfo$().then(onLoad)
}

// Вызов функций
getUsersInfo(users => console.log(JSON.stringify(users)));

setTimeout(() => {
  getUsersIds$ = () => Promise.resolve([]);
  getUsersInfo(users => console.log(JSON.stringify(users))); // []
}, 1000);
```

Comment: добавь пояснения в код, а то черт ногу сломит :)

Comment: У меня самодокументированный код!! добавил)

Comment: плохая документация - стоит переписать :-D

Comment: Надеюсь — это шутка про код) Потому что комментарии переписывать я не хотю)

Comment: Это было про "самодокументируемость" :-)

Comment: @vp_arth, можете, пожалуйста, объяснить эти части кода?
1. почему вы пишете так : const [i, id]
2.и что означает этот вызов ? getUsersInfo(users => console.log(JSON.stringify(users)));

Comment: 1. Object.entries итерирует по парам [ключ, значение], так мне не нужно вести дополнительный итератор индекса в массиве, можете на for(let i-0;...) переписать. 2. Ну, это просто вызов реализованной функции, чтобы показать что она работает..

Comment: @vp_arth к сожалению, это решение не проходит один тест.. getUsersInfo должна возвращать пользовательскую информацию в правильном порядке (505ms)

Comment: Сколько всего тестов? А ссылки на тестирующую систему нет?

Comment: @vp_arth ссылки нет, второй тест, который прошел нормально : getUsersInfo должна возвращать пустой массив если пользователей нет

Comment: Добавил в демку асинхронности, чтобы убедиться, что порядок верный.

Comment: Ааа, я кажется понял) Всё наоборот) На самом деле, второй тест должен был упасть, а первый пройти) Возможно там какие-нибудь крестики/галочки неочевидные =)

Answer (score 0):

```
const { getUserInfo, getUsersIds } = db;

function getUsersInfo(onLoad) {
  getUsersIds((ids) => {
    const users = [];
    let count = 0;
    ids.forEach((id, index) => {
      getUserInfo(id, (userInfo) => {
        users[index] = userInfo;
        count++;
        if (count === ids.length) {
          onLoad(users);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]